# It is useful and dear?

Tags: discussion

When I hover over the up button I see:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and dear.

And when I hover over the down button, I see that the question is

> undear

I find this rather endearing.

Is this a typo no one has noticed, or are my eyes making things undear?

Comment: Think it must be your eyes, I'm not seeing this. Could you post images from your screen? It seems vaguely possible that it could be related to browser/font stuff.

Comment: The fonts used for some SE sites aren't the best for readability. We had a similar situation on ELL where half the folks reading [What is the meaning of “daisy pom”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/58767/) saw P-O-M as P-O-R-N. The kerning seems out of whack sometimes.

Comment: It's probably not 'dear' but 'clear', 'c' and 'l' close together look like 'd'

Comment: This question is both useful and dear. So I upvotes. I  fact we see the word we expect to see. So often the meaning of the sentence is so dear in context that even if it is a typo (which it is not here) many readers see nothing wrong and fail to spot the typo: it is naturally read as either 'dear' or 'clear' in order to make sense in the particular situation.

Comment: Thank all, for the input.  When I first read the comment of @ColleenV, I read daisy p-o-m.  No problem, I thought.  But now it looks like daisy p-o-r-n and then it flicks back to daisy p-o-m.  Flick, flick, back and forth. I know my eyes aren't the best!

Comment: Press "ctrl" (or apple "option-command") and "+" to increase the font size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's definitely "clear" and not "dear". It would probably help to include details of your hardware and screen settings. If you are using a display which is not set at its native resolution you may experience this phenomenon, especially if your display is anti-aliased.

The screenshot below is actual-size, which means that it may look exactly the same as what you see. However, the image is a link to a full-size version, which should allow you see the word *clear*ly.

[image: Screenshot of up-arrow]

Comment: Thanks.  When I blow up the settings and squint I can see a tiny space between the c and the l